# PHP 5.3 patch for password_hash() erroring

Tags: php, php-password-hash

Working on my first project which requires secure authentication. My hosting is still on PHP 5.3.27 so I'm using the password_hash() compatibility patch [found here.](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) My issue is that `return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost'=>$cost));` errors out stating that $password must be a string. Why is it not a string? I don't even know where to start debugging.

HTML which gets the password

```
<form method='post' action='register.php' name='loginform'>
    <label for="inputpass">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputpass" placeholder="Enter a password">
</form>
```

contents of register.php

```
<?php

require 'validate.php';

$password = $_POST['password'];
var_dump(validations::generate_hash($password));

?>
```

contents of validate.php *password.php is the 5.3 compatibility patch for password_hash()*

```
<?php

require 'plugins/password.php';

class validations {

    function generate_hash($password){

        $cost = 11;

        return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost'=>$cost));

    }

    function validate_pw($password, $hash){

        return crypt($password, $hash)==$hash;

    }   
}

?>
```

Comment: Form elements need a `name` attribute to be passed through in the request

Comment: _“I don't even know where to start debugging”_ – well doing a `var_dump($password)` before passing it to the method would be a start … and then to **enable proper error_reporting** after that!

Comment: I can't see the error you reported, but why are verifying using `crypt` rather than `password_verify` in the verification step?

Comment: @IMSoP leftover from when I was still using crypt. I was updating to use `password_hash()`

Comment: php.ini defaults have been changed to `error_reporting = E_ALL`! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Also see Openwall's [PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its portable and hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords. The guy who wrote the framework (SolarDesigner) is the same guy who wrote [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) and sits as a judge in the [Password Hashing Competition](http://password-hashing.net/). So he knows a thing or two about attacks on passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `$password` is not a string but the `null` value¹. That's because `$_POST` does not have key named `password`², which in turn happens because you do not have an input element with `name="password` in your form.

Adding a name attribute will make things work:

```
<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="inputpass"
       placeholder="Enter a password">
```

¹ You can verify this with `var_dump($password)`.

² This will cause PHP to emit an `E_NOTICE` message at the line you are making the assignment. Turning `error_reporting` to the maximum with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` would make this message appear.

Comment: I'm clearly in need of sleep. Every other input on my form (i clipped that bit out) has a name attached. Thanks for the sanity check.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading your code and yo have some errors in the HTML form.

First you must to use " instead ' in attribute.
Second you must set a name attribute in the input tag.

In the other hand I was trying to run your code in my computer but unfortuantely I don have the PHP version 5.5 to run password_hash.

Also remember you must set your methods as follows :

```
public static function generate_hash($password)
{
    $cost = 11;
    return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => $cost));
}
```

because your var_dump() is :

```
var_dump(validations::generate_hash($password));
```

I suggest too try the next line of code to validate your $_POST

```
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
```

I think thats all.